# PHP/MYSQL subquery causing undefined index error

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

I am trying to do a subquery using PDO:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT sum(ros_ranking) FROM (SELECT ros_ranking FROM players WHERE teamid = 1 and positionid = 1 ORDER BY ros_ranking ASC LIMIT 1) AS totalrankings");
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$num_rows= $stmt->rowCount();
echo "tqr= ".$row['totalrankings'];
```

I keep getting `Notice: Undefined index: totalrankings in ...`

ros_ranking is definitely a field with numbers in it in my Players table and a teamid of 1 and positionid of 1 definitely exist.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?  FYI, if I do just the subquery as the main query, it works.  So something must be wrong with `SELECT sum(ros_ranking) FROM` or `AS totalrankings`  but they seem pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong alias use/position

you need  a column name alias for totalrankings (not a table name alias as you have done)

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT sum(t.ros_ranking) totalrankings
        FROM (SELECT ros_ranking 
                FROM players 
                WHERE teamid = 1 
                AND positionid = 1 
                ORDER BY ros_ranking ASC LIMIT 1)  t");
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$num_rows= $stmt->rowCount();
echo "tqr= ".$row['totalrankings'];
```

Answer (score 1):

`total_rankings` is an alias for the subquery, it's not an alias for the column. You need to put `AS totalrankings` after the `SUM()` expression.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("
    SELECT sum(ros_ranking) AS totalrankings 
    FROM (
        SELECT ros_ranking 
        FROM players 
        WHERE teamid = 1 and positionid = 1 
        ORDER BY ros_ranking ASC
        LIMIT 1) AS subquery");
```

But `LIMIT 1` in the subquery means you're not going to get a sum of anything. The subquery just returns 1 row, and the sum of one thing is just that value.

Answer (score 0):

Though you can fix it, by giving the selected column the right alias, there is no need to fetch an array if your query returns only one column. Use [`fetchColumn()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) instead:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT ...");
$stmt->execute();
$totalrankings = $stmt->fetchColumn();
$num_rows= $stmt->rowCount();
echo "tqr= ".$totalrankings;
```